# How do I swap between Unity-2D and Ubuntu Classic?

Tags: unity-2d, gnome-classic

I have changed my system to Unity-2d, I believe it's called, and would like to get back to Ubuntu Classic but don't know how.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3):

Sure.
First logout. Then as shown below in image, select Ubuntu Classic instead Ubuntu 2D

Ubuntu 11.04

[image]

Ubuntu 11.10

[image]

Comment: I don't know if I would ever have figured it out alone. Thanks Zetah. - bri <3